# Zend and google fusion table

Tags: php, api, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table containing postcodes.
I'm trying to access it using PHP.

After hours, I've managed to get something display (Select) using Zend.
I'm now able to display the body of the Http response.

But I can't find a way to do a 'foreach' for each postcode (I need to update another column for each postcode).

My code:

```
$data = $gdata->get($url);

$postcodes = $data->getRawBody();   
foreach ($postcodes as $codes)
{
    echo "postcode: ". $codes. "<br/>";
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($postcodes);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

So, the foreach returns an error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

And the dump:
string(147555) "name
AB10 1
AB10 6
AB10 7
AB11 5
AB11 6
AB11 7
AB11 8
AB11 9
AB12 3

Comment: Managed to 'solve' it:     $postcodes = $data->getRawBody();
    
    $codes = split ( "\n", $postcodes);
     
  foreach ($codes as $entry)
 {
  echo "postcode:" . $entry . "<br/>";
 }

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it

```
$postcodes = $data->getRawBody(); 
$codes = split ( "\n", $postcodes);

foreach ($codes as $entry) 
{ 
    echo "postcode:" . $entry . "<br/>"; 
}
```